# CSS gradient fits only viewport

Tags: css

In the following page, the css gradient is correctly rendert, if the viewport is higher than `#container` (600px). But if the viewport is only 400px, then the gradient is missing at the bottom 200px (outside the viewport).

How can I fix that?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="de">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Test-Site for css gradient</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    body {
    margin: 0;
    }

    html, body, #body-wrapper {
        height: 100%
    }

    #body-wrapper {
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-image: -webkit-gradient(
            linear,
            left top, left bottom,
            from(rgba(131,20,20,1)),
            to(rgba(243,172,149,1)),
            color-stop(0.2, rgba(159,19,24,1)),
            color-stop(0.7, rgba(222,0,30,1))
        );
        background-image: 
        -webkit-linear-gradient(
            top,
            rgba(131,20,20,1),
            rgba(159,19,24,1) 20%,
            rgba(222,0,30,1) 70%,
            rgba(243,172,149,1)
        );
        background-image: 
        -moz-linear-gradient(
            top,
            rgba(131,20,20,1),
            rgba(159,19,24,1) 20%,
            rgba(222,0,30,1) 70%,
            rgba(243,172,149,1)
        );
        background-image: 
        -o-linear-gradient(
            top,
            rgba(131,20,20,1),
            rgba(159,19,24,1) 20%,
            rgba(222,0,30,1) 70%,
            rgba(243,172,149,1)
        );
        background-image: 
        linear-gradient(
            top,
            rgba(131,20,20,1),
            rgba(159,19,24,1) 20%,
            rgba(222,0,30,1) 70%,
            rgba(243,172,149,1)
        );
    }

    #container {
        max-width: 900px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        background: #fff;
        border: 1px solid black;
        height: 600px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="body-wrapper">
    <div id="container">

    </div>
  </div>

</webl:context>  
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT: Here you can see it online: [Test-Site](http://betschmann.ch/test.html)

Answer (score 0):

Have to ever try this style in #container:

```
display:block;
overflow:hidden;
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because `height: 100%` sets the height of the document, the `<body>` element, and your `<div id="body-wrapper">` to match the viewport (which, in this case, is less than the height of the content).

Add `min-height: 600px` to `html, body, #body-wrapper`?

Comment: min-height: 600px works - but what to do if the #container has no predef height eg 'auto'?